# Как в web-чате организовать механизм Presence?

Tags: java, чат

Доброго дня.
В любом чате должен присутствовать механизм, отслеживающий весь список контактов на присутствие в сети (*online*). Он называется *presence*. Вопрос:   
Какие есть механизмы *presense*, которые не перегружают сильно процессор, оперативную память или БД.  
Сложность у меня возникла с вопросом, как организовать запросы в БД, которые будут возвращать клиенту только список его контактов с пометками online/offline.  
Спасибо.

Comment: Например  вариант: держать в памяти HashMap username -> status. Запрашивать из базы контакт-лист и для выбранных записей вытаскивать статусы.

Хранить статусы в базе нет особого смысла, т.к. если сервер не запущен, то, очевидно, все клиенты не в сети.

Comment: @Nofate Спасибо за комментарий.    
Предполагается, что web-сервер всегда запущен.    
И вы полагаете, что есть смысл держать постоянно в памяти список всех зарегистрированных пользователей? И, допустим, чтобы обновлять статусы всех контактов для каждого пользователя, который онлайн и которому надо предоставлять информацию о статусах всех его контактов, каждые секунду-две, сервер не перегрузится?

Comment: Странно делать предположения о нагрузке, не имя никаких данных ни о количестве пользователей, ни о железе сервера. 

В любом случае roundtrip в базу никак не выйдет экономичнее, чем обращение к данным в хэшмапе.

Comment: Что если реализован какой-то хитрый механизм, позволяющий экономично использовать сервер во время отслеживания всех кто онлайн и для каждого отдельного списка контактов. Может, кто видел его когда-нибудь и поведает о нем?)

Comment: Попробуйте SQL Server Notification Services. Можно подписаться на изменение БД. Статус меняется - меняется(появляется) запись БД - событие. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Механизм вам не подскажу, но если бы я делал то привязал бы это к сессии, вам в любом случае в ней хранить данные юзера.

Предположим есть класс **User** который мы будем хранить в сессии после логина методом

```
session.setAttribute("user", user ).
```

делаем листенер

```
public class LoginsListener implements HttpSessionAttributeListener {

    private static final Set<Long> logins = new HashSet<Long>();

    public static boolean isUserOnline( long id ) {
        return logins.contains(id);
    }
    @Override
    public void attributeAdded(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        String name = event.getName();
        User user = (User) event.getValue();
        if (  name.equals("user") && user!=null  ) {
              logins.add( user.getId()  );
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeRemoved(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        String name = event.getName();
        User user = (User) event.getValue();
        if (  name.equals("user") && user!=null  ) {
              logins.remove( user.getId()  );
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void attributeReplaced(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {

    }
}
```

он реагирует на изменение атрибутов в сессии, соответственно, когда добавляете в сессию данные о юзере, перехватываете это событие и заносите/удаляете его из множества Set<Long> - айдишников юзеров

Теперь любого юзера можно проверить  по id, id контактов тоже можно хранить в сессии в виде множества Set ну и соответственно пробегаться по ним и проверять с помощью метода

```
isUserOnline(id)
```

Код не совсем идеальный(не потокобезопасный и нет дополнительных проверок), но основную идею передает, все остальное можно дописать самому.

Что касается нагрузки то такой способ менее затратный и более быстрый во всем, кроме потребления памяти, хотя на самом деле и памяти то он не много будет забирать.

Также возможно придется повешать слушатель на добавление/удаление сессии, просто уже не помню срабатывает ли attributeRemoved при удалении сессии. Ну и прописать слушатели в web.xml